# Recording of anonymous edits of text on page

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following code, I am allowing users to edit text content, save and recall changes from own "local storage". So every editor's browser "remembers" their own editing, and each editor sees his changes only. I want to realise an idea of the anonymous wiki and import every user edits and display the last one in the final HTML page.

```js
function saveEdits() {

    //get the editable element
    var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");

    //get the edited element content
    var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;

    //save the content to local storage
    localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;

    //write a confirmation to the user
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Готово";

}

function checkEdits() {

    //find out if the user has previously saved edits
    if (localStorage.userEdits !== null)
        document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
}
```

```css
body {
    display: block;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 50px;
    width: 90%;
    font-family: 'Oranienbaum', serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    height: 90%
}
#edit {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: inherit;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Oranienbaum', serif;
}
#button {
    background-color: silver;
    border: none;
    top: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Oranienbaum', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#update {
    background-color: white;
    top: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.footer {
    background-color: inherit;
    top: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Indexmod Encyclopedia — anonymous real-time editing </title>
    <script src="code.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oranienbaum');
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="checkEdits()">

    Indexmod Россия

    <hr>
    <div id="edit" contenteditable="true">
        Here is Indexmod Encyclopedia anonymous real-time editing sandbox area
    </div>

    <hr>

    <input type="button" id=button value="Сохранить" onclick="saveEdits()" />

    <div id="update">Редактируй текст и нажми сохранить до следующего раза</div>

    <p class="footer" id="footer"><span><script src="footer.js"></script></span>
    </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're going to set item on local storage, the method goes to:

```
localStorage.setItem('userEdits', userVersion);
```

And get item

```
localStorage.getItem('userEdits');
```

Hope it would be help, This works for me.

See the reference: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp